# MySqli not throwing errors - why?

Tags: php, mysql, exception, mysqli

I have some pretty simple code that's not throwing an exception on a client server.

The problem is that the table `mytable` doesn't exist. Fair enough. But then it should throw an exception... or is there some unusual MySqli setup that would prevent an exception from being thrown?

Code is below:

```
    $query = "DROP TABLE `mytable`";
    try {
        $db->query($query);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        //LOG THE ERROR
    }
```

Comment: Did you try adding error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` - `try/catch` may not be enough. What about adding `print $e->getMessage();`

Comment: Have you set `$db->report_mode = MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT;`

Comment: Great work Mark - it was the MYSQL_REPORT_STRICT that was needed. Thanks!