# Connecting PHP to mySQL on osX Sierra

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, web-deployment

I'm quite new to `PHP` and `MySQL`. I'm using the Mac OS Sierra pre installed copies of `Apache` and `PHP`. I've downloaded and configure `MySQL` (works absolutely fine, able to use `CRUD` and so on). However, I've been struggling to connect from `PHP` to the database. I have this code:

```
<?php
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "mgs";
    $dbpass = "pass1";
    $dbname = "widget_corp";
    $connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        die("Database connection failed " .
             mysqli_connect_error() .
             "(".mysqli_connect_errno().")"
           );
    }

?>

<!doctype html>

    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Conn</title>

        </head>

        <body>


        </body>

    </html>
<?php
    mysqli_close($connection);

?>
```

I've saved it as a `.php` file
However I keep getting this error when i try to open the `.php` file from a browser:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in
>   /Users/Mahfouz/Sites/connect_prac.php on line 6 Database connection
>   failed No such file or directory(2002)

I've created the User and Database referenced in the code.
what am I doing wrong? how do I get this working?
thanks

PS: I've looked at similar questions on this website, but I haven't been able to apply any of the given solutions to my situation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676688/php-mysql-connection-not-working-2002-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: "CRUD" is something you do with a web stack as it refers specifically to [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer). It can't be done with MySQL alone. Now before you get too far into `mysqli`, do try and use the [object-oriented interface](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php) via `new mysqli(...)` and not the obsolete PHP 4 era procedural one. It makes errors much more obvious. Also [turn on exception reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23816633/mysqli-not-throwing-errors-why).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I followed these steps and it worked:

cd /var
mkdir mysql
cd mysql
ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock mysql.sock

gotten from: https://jason.pureconcepts.net/2016/09/install-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x-sierra/